# Getting "Type Error" when using WebAuthn on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, webauthn

I'm trying to work with WebAuthn for the first time. Everything works well on Android and Windows, however on IOS, I'm getting **TypeError: Type Error** when calling navigator.credentials.create or navigator.credentials.get.

Here is an example screen shot of the publicKey I'm using on create:

[image]

JavaScript:

```
try {
        newCredential = await navigator.credentials.create({
            publicKey: makeCredentialOptions
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e.toString());
        return;
    }
```

I'm using the following demo code from https://github.com/passwordless-lib/fido2-net-lib#examples as an example, and my JavaScript looks pretty much the same as in the demo.

Tried with Safari and Chrome, on IOS versions 15.5 and 16.3, on all I get the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That error is pretty cryptic indeed. Do other demos work, like https://passwordless.id or https://webauthn.io? ...just to know if it's a platform/browser specific issue or something with your implementation.

Comment: This error only occurs on old versions of iOS. There's no such error starting iOS 16 up.

Answer (score 4):

I spent about an hour figuring this out and eventually found that Safari seems to require a `residentKey` being set.

So I tried this and the `Type Error` went away. Apple really need to work on their error messages... utterly useless.

```
      const credential = await startRegistration({
        ...publicKey,
        authenticatorSelection: {
          requireResidentKey: true,
          residentKey: "required",
        },
      });
```

Now I know this is the problem, I need to look into how to make my server code respond with this correctly.

Hope this helps!